# removing duplicated words from an array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicated words from an array, and I keep getting null values. I'm not allowed to use java sorting methods so I have to develop my own. Here's my code:

```
public class Duplicate{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] test = {"a", "b", "abvc", "abccc", "a", "bbc", "ccc", "abc", "bbc"};
        removeDuplicate(test);
    }
    public static String[] removeDuplicate(String[] words){
        boolean [] isDuplicate = new boolean[words.length];
        int i,j;
        String[] tmp = new String[words.length];

        for (i = 0; i < words.length ; i++){

            if (isDuplicate[i])
                continue;

            for(j = 0; j < words.length ; j++){
                if (words[i].equals(words[j])) {
                    isDuplicate[j] = true;
                    tmp[i] = words[i];
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<words.length;i++)
            System.out.println(tmp[i]);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I tried doing

```
if(words == null)
   words == "";
```

But it doesn't work. I also want to return the tmp array with a new size.
For example, test array length = 9, after removing the duplicates,I should get a new array with a length of 7.Thank you for your help.
EDIT:
result i get:

```
a
b
abvc
abccc
null
bbc
ccc
abc
null
```

Comment: Where is the npe? At what line?

Comment: @brso05 i get null values on my results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about this approach?

```
public static String[] removeDuplicate(String[] words){
    // remember which word is a duplicate
    boolean[] isDuplicate = new boolean[words.length];
    // and count them
    int countDuplicate = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length ; i++){
        // only check "forward" because "backwards checked" duplicates have been marked yet
        for(int j = i + 1; j < words.length ; j++){
            if (words[i].equals(words[j])) {
                isDuplicate[j] = true;
                countDuplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
    // collect non-duplicate strings
    String[] tmp = new String[words.length - countDuplicate];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < isDuplicate.length; i++) {
        if (isDuplicate[i] == false) {
            tmp[j] = words[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    // and return them
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add explanations to your answers, not just a block of code and expect people to understand what you're doing. Also, @ArcRanges, this is more or less the same answer I had put in my edit.

Comment: @McAdam331 I totally agree that this solution is not a good one in general and I'd prefer something with a `List` or `Set` too. I just took the original code and added some extra lines and short comments just to show how it could be done with the given "tool set" (considering the other comments here, there might be some non-technical reasons for not using an "easier" solution).

Comment: @jCoder fair enough, but this could still be done a little better, too. You loop through the entire isDuplicate array, what happens if the array is 100 strings long, and the last 90 are duplicates (unlikely, but still possible)? You'll end up doing 90 unnecessary iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting nulls because the result array contains fewer words than the input array. However, you're constructing the arrays of the same length.

You don't have to sort to solve this problem. However, if you're not allowed to use the tools provided by java.utils, then this is either a poorly contrived test question or whomever told you not to use the Java utility classes is poorly informed.

You can solve without sorting by doing (assuming Java 1.5+):

```
public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"a", "b", "abvc", "abccc", "a", "bbc", "ccc", "abc", "bbc"};
        String[] deduped = removeDuplicate(test);
        print(deduped);
    }

    public static String[] removeDuplicate(String[] words) {
        Set<String> wordSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for (String word : words) {
            wordSet.add(word);
        }
        return wordSet.toArray(new String[wordSet.size()]);
    }

    public static void print(String[] words) {
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
a
b
abvc
abccc
bbc
ccc
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this with a different approach. If you can use an ArrayList, why not just create one of those, and add the non-duplicate values to it, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> uniqueArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   if(!uniqueArrayList.contains(words[i])){ // If the value isn't in the list already
      uniqueArrayList.add(words[i]);
   }
}
```

Now, you have an array list of all of your values without the duplicates. If you need to, you can work on converting that back to a regular array.

**EDIT**

I really think you should use the above option if you can, as there is no clean or decently efficient way to do this only using arrays. However, if you must, you can do something like this:

You can use the code you have to mark values as null if they are duplicates, and also create a counter to see how many unique values you have, like this:

```
int uniqueCounter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < isDuplicate.length; i++){
   if(!isDuplicate[i]){
      uniqueCounter++;
   }
}
```

Then, you can create a new array of the size of unique items, and loop through the words and add non-duplicate values.

```
String[] uniqueArray = new String[uniqueCounter];
int uniqueIndex = 0;
int wordsIndex = 0;
while(index < uniqueArray.length){
   // Check if words index is not a duplicate
   if(!isDuplicate[wordsIndex]){
      // Add to array
      uniqueArray[uniqueIndex] = words[wordsIndex];
      uniqueIndex++; // Need to move to next spot in unique.
   }
   // Need to move to next spot in words
   wordsIndex++;
}
```

Again, I **HIGHLY** recommend against something like this. It is very poor, and pains me to write, but for the sake of example on how it *could* be done using an array, you can try it.

Comment: I have not learned how to use array.list yet, so I might get mark deductions if I use that...

Comment: I would hope no deductions for using something new, but I will try to edit with another option.

Comment: I would definitely go with your answer since it is very efficient, but I'm afraid my instructor would question me...

Comment: @ArcRanges try the edit. If you have time to ask before turning it in, it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for hashset to remove duplicates, it will remove duplicates since hash function for the same string will give same value, and duplicates will be eliminated. Then you can convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to write functioning code, but I would reccomend to first sort the array using `Arrays.sort(stringArray)` and then loop throug the array coparing one string to the previous. Strings that match the previous one are duplicates. 
**Note:** This method is probably not the fastest one and though only should be used on small arrays or in tasks where performance does not matter.